# Object[key] returns undefined (strange)

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I've had a weird behaviour from an object.

```
var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
canvas.style.display = 'none';
document.body.appendChild(canvas);

var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
//imgObj is an Image Object
ctx.drawImage(imgObj, 0, 0);

//inserting(caching) the image data in the spriteData object
var spriteCoordinates = coordinates.spriteCoordinates; 
//coordinates.spriteCoordinates has keys in integer

for(var i in spriteCoordinates){
    var x = spriteCoordinates[i].x,
        y = spriteCoordinates[i].y,
        w = spriteCoordinates[i].w,
        h = spriteCoordinates[i].h;

    var imageData = ctx.getImageData(x, y, w, h);

    spriteData[i] = imageData;
}
```

When I console.log `spriteData`, I get:

```
Object { }
```

[image]

When I click on it, I get:

```
0: {
    width: int,
    height: int,
    data: array()
}// I've put int and array just for representation
```

[image]

But when I console.log `spriteData[0]` (`spriteData['0']`), I get `undefined`.
And I've even tried to console.log `Object.keys(spriteData)`, but I get an empty array.

Can someone tell me please what's going on?

**EDIT**

After some manipulation I found that this was cause when I put this function in the `onload` method of the `Image` object. But outside of it the object was *normal*.

Comment: is `coordinates.spriteCoordinates` an Array? try replacing your `for ... in` with a regular for-loop if it is, running `for ... in` over an Array can result in very weird behaviour.

Comment: @GNi33 No, it's an Object having integer as keys

Comment: Are you able to put together a short example of your unexpected behaviour on jsFiddle?

Comment: @Phylogenesis, I've tried it on jsbin to have the console http://jsbin.com/gamimahiga/2/edit?js,console,output

Comment: Though I don't know why I get an error in getImageData in the jsbin

Comment: @Xlander, after fix error with loading img, your jsbin seems to work - [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/yuwiqefuwi/1/edit?js,console)

Comment: @Grundy, can you show me please?

Comment: @Xlander, you can go by link above - it work.

Comment: @Xlander this - http://jsbin.com/yuwiqefuwi/1/edit?js,console

Comment: @Grundy, Ah because of the `crossOrigin`. But I don't use external images in my project(all included in the project), it's just that the structure of the object is weird when the block codes is inside the `onload` but outside it works...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74229/discussion-between-grundy-and-xlander).

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using the `for..in` loop, use the more semantic [`.map()`](http://devdocs.io/javascript/global_objects/array/map):

```
var spriteData = Object.keys(spriteCoordinates).map(function(key) {
    var item = spriteCoordinates[key];
    return ctx.getImageData(item.x, item.y, item.w, item.h);
});
```

- `Object.keys(spriteCoordinates).map(fn)` - Take an array made of the keys of the `spriteCoordinates` object, and transform it into an array
- `fn` is a function, `.map()` will iterate over the array, apply the function on each item, and construct a new array from the result.

The result is a new array which you directly assign to spriteData.

Comment: Thank you. It's a simpler(and lesser to write) way of assigning values. But I've found the problem... But still don't know why it was having that behaviour.